# How to pass object across functions?

Tags: python, function

learning and incorporating functions into a web-scraping project in python and ran into this problem. Basically I want to pass an object (pandas `dataframe`) to another function / across functions. Basically I want to pass y to out across functions: `out.append(y)`.

```
def do_inner_thing(y):
    y = y + 1
    out.append(y)
    
def do_outer_thing():
    out = []
    x = 2
    do_inner_thing(x)
    print(out)

do_outer_thing()

#Desired Output: 3
```

Comment: It's not very clear, but I think you should use the `return` keyword in the `do_inner_thing` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a **`return`** statement - have the function return an object using statement of the same name.  Also, variables inside functions are *local*, not global, so they can't be accessed from other functions.  You'll need to pass your list as well.  Something like:

```
def do_inner_thing(y, out):
    y = y + 1
    out.append(y)
    return out
    
def do_outer_thing():
    out = []
    x = 2
    out = do_inner_thing(x, out)
    print(out)

do_outer_thing()
```

Comment: the `return out` and `out = ` with `do_inner_thing(..)` are completely unnecessary.  Lists are mutable, and `out.append(y)` does all the work that's necessary.

Comment: That'd be true if it were declared outside of the method - but that'll return a NameError/not defined error since it's scope is limited to the function

Comment: The return statement was what I needed, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped!  Please mark as correct/answered if that did it

Comment: @AlecZ.  I repeat my comment.  I just tried it in an interpreter and it did exactly what it was supposed to do.  Remove the "return out" from the first function and the "out =" from the second function and the code works fine.  The `out.append(y)` modifies `out`, and the caller sees this change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this is what you meant or not but you're able to place 'out' outside of the function and make do_inner_thing(y) print the string of out.

```
out = []
def do_inner_thing(y):
    y = y + 1
    out.append(y)
    
def do_outer_thing():
    x = 2
    do_inner_thing(x)
    print(str(out)[1])

do_outer_thing()
```